# Intel® Xeon® Scalable Processors - Do they support 'Flex Mode'?

Tags: memory, xeon, multi-channel

Intel has a memory mode called [Flex Mode](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html#flex)

Is this mode supported by Xeon-SP CPU's (specifically 1st gen Xeon Platinum CPUs)? I couldn't find a list of CPUs supporting this mode and not sure if this is by now a standard feature of all Intel CPUs maybe?

Comment: Please be more specific about which Xeon processors you are asking about exactly by providing that information in the question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a motherboard and chip set feature, not related to Processor specifically.

**If any of these boards support Xeon processors, then yes.**

[Found here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html) under Related Products (Use Show All link) at bottom of page

Desktop Board D2500CCIntel®

Desktop Board D2500HNIntel®

Desktop Board D2550DC2Intel®

Desktop Board D2550MUD2Intel®

Desktop Board D2700DCIntel®

Desktop Board D2700MUDIntel®

Desktop Board D425KTIntel®

Desktop Board D525MWIntel®

Desktop Board DN2800MTIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® B75 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DB75ENIntel®

Desktop Board DH61AGIntel®

Desktop Board DH61AGLIntel®

Desktop Board DH61BEIntel®

Desktop Board DH61BFIntel®

Desktop Board DH61CRIntel® Desktop

Board DH61DLIntel®

Desktop Board DH61HOIntel®

Desktop Board DH61KVCHIntel®

Desktop Board DH61SAIntel®

Desktop Board DH61SKCHIntel®

Desktop Board DH61WWIntel®

Desktop Board DH61ZEIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® H67 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DH67BLIntel®

Desktop Board DH67CFIntel®

Desktop Board DH67CLIntel®

Desktop Board DH67GDIntel®

Desktop Board DH67VRIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® H77 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DH77DFIntel®

Desktop Board DH77EBIntel®

Desktop Board DH77KCIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® H87 ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DH87MCIntel®

Desktop Board DH87RLIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Q67 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DQ67EPIntel®

Desktop Board DQ67OWIntel®

Desktop Board DQ67SWIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Q77 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DQ77CPIntel®

Desktop Board DQ77KBIntel®

Desktop Board DQ77MKIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Q87 ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DQ87PGIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® X79 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DX79SIIntel®

Desktop Board DX79SRIntel®

Desktop Board DX79TOIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Z68 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DZ68AFIntel®

Desktop Board DZ68BCIntel®

Desktop Board DZ68DBIntel®

Desktop Board DZ68PLIntel®

Desktop Board DZ68ZVIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Z75 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DZ75ML-45KIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Z77 Express ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DZ77BH-55KIntel®

Desktop Board DZ77GA-70KIntel®

Desktop Board DZ77RE-75KIntel®

Desktop Board DZ77SL-50KIntel®

Desktop Boards with Intel® Z87 ChipsetIntel®

Desktop Board DZ87KLT-75KLegacy Intel®

Desktop BoardsIntel®

Desktop Board CA810EIntel®

Desktop Board D101GGCIntel®

Desktop Board D102GGC2Intel®

Desktop Board D201GLYIntel®

Desktop Board D201GLY2Intel®

Desktop Board D410PTIntel®

Desktop Board D510MOIntel®

Desktop Board D5400XSIntel®

Desktop Board D815EFVIntel®

Desktop Board D815EPFVIntel®

Desktop Board D845EBG2Intel®

Desktop Board D845EBTIntel®

Desktop Board D845EPIIntel®

Desktop Board D845EPT2Intel®

Desktop Board D845GBVIntel®

Desktop Board D845GEBV2Intel®

Desktop Board D845GERG2Intel®

Desktop Board D845GLADIntel®

Desktop Board D845GLLYIntel®

Desktop Board D845GLVAIntel®

Desktop Board D845GRGIntel®

Desktop Board D845GVAD2Intel®

Desktop Board D845GVFNIntel®

Desktop Board D845GVSRIntel®

Desktop Board D845HVIntel®

Desktop Board D845PEBT2Intel®

Desktop Board D845PECEIntel®

Desktop Board D845PEMYIntel®

Desktop Board D845PESVIntel®

Desktop Board D845WNIntel®

Desktop Board D848PMBIntel®

Desktop Board D850EMD2Intel®

Desktop Board D850EMV2Intel®

Desktop Board D850GBIntel®

Desktop Board D850MVSEIntel®

Desktop Board D865GBFIntel®

Desktop Board D865GLCIntel®

Desktop Board D865GRHIntel®

Desktop Board D865GSAIntel®

Desktop Board D865GVHZIntel®

Desktop Board D865PCDIntel®

Desktop Board D865PCKIntel®

Desktop Board D865PERLIntel®

Desktop Board D875PBZIntel®

Desktop Board D910GLDWIntel®

Desktop Board D915GAGIntel®

Desktop Board D915GAVIntel®

Desktop Board D915GEVIntel®

Desktop Board D915GLVGIntel®

Desktop Board D915GMHIntel®

Desktop Board D915GUXIntel®

Desktop Board D915GVWBIntel®

Desktop Board D915PBLIntel®

Desktop Board D915PCMIntel®

Desktop Board D915PCYIntel®

Desktop Board D915PDTIntel®

Desktop Board D915PGNIntel®

Desktop Board D915PLWDIntel®

Desktop Board D915PSYIntel®

Desktop Board D925XBCIntel®

Desktop Board D925XCVIntel®

Desktop Board D925XEBC2Intel®

Desktop Board D925XECV2Intel®

Desktop Board D925XHYIntel®

Desktop Board D945GBOIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCCRIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCLIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCLFIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCLF2Intel®

Desktop Board D945GCNLIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCPEIntel®

Desktop Board D945GCZIntel®

Desktop Board D945GNTIntel®

Desktop Board D945GPMIntel®

Desktop Board D945GRWIntel®

Desktop Board D945GSEJTIntel®

Desktop Board D945GTPIntel®

Desktop Board D945GZCC2Intel®

Desktop Board D945PAWIntel®

Desktop Board D945PDKIntel®

Desktop Board D945PLNMIntel®

Desktop Board D945PLRNIntel®

Desktop Board D945PSNIntel®

Desktop Board D945PVSIntel®

Desktop Board D945PWMIntel®

Desktop Board D946GZABIntel®

Desktop Board D946GZISIntel®

Desktop Board D946GZTSIntel®

Desktop Board D955XBKIntel®

Desktop Board D955XCSIntel®

Desktop Board D975XBXIntel®

Desktop Board D975XBX2Intel®

Desktop Board DB43LDIntel®

Desktop Board DB65ALIntel®

Desktop Board DG31GLIntel®

Desktop Board DG31PRIntel®

Desktop Board DG31PRBRIntel®

Desktop Board DG33BUIntel®

Desktop Board DG33FBIntel®

Desktop Board DG33TLIntel®

Desktop Board DG35ECIntel®

Desktop Board DG41ANIntel®

Desktop Board DG41BIIntel®

Desktop Board DG41CNIntel®

Desktop Board DG41KRIntel®

Desktop Board DG41MJIntel®

Desktop Board DG41RQIntel®

Desktop Board DG41TXIntel®

Desktop Board DG41TYIntel®

Desktop Board DG41WVIntel®

Desktop Board DG43GTIntel®

Desktop Board DG43NBIntel®

Desktop Board DG43RKIntel®

Desktop Board DG45FCIntel®

Desktop Board DG45IDIntel®

Desktop Board DG965MQIntel®

Desktop Board DG965MSIntel®

Desktop Board DG965OTIntel®

Desktop Board DG965PZIntel®

Desktop Board DG965RYIntel®

Desktop Board DG965SSIntel®

Desktop Board DG965WHIntel®

Desktop Board DH55HCIntel®

Desktop Board DH55PJIntel®

Desktop Board DH55TCIntel®

Desktop Board DH57DDIntel®

Desktop Board DH57JGIntel®

Desktop Board DP35DPIntel®

Desktop Board DP43BFIntel®

Desktop Board DP43BFLIntel®

Desktop Board DP43TFIntel®

Desktop Board DP45SGIntel®

Desktop Board DP55KGIntel®

Desktop Board DP55SBIntel®

Desktop Board DP55WBIntel®

Desktop Board DP55WGIntel®

Desktop Board DP67BAIntel®

Desktop Board DP67BGIntel®

Desktop Board DP67DEIntel®

Desktop Board DP965LTIntel®

Desktop Board DQ33HSIntel®

Desktop Board DQ35JOIntel®

Desktop Board DQ35MPIntel®

Desktop Board DQ43APIntel®

Desktop Board DQ45CBIntel®

Desktop Board DQ45EKIntel®

Desktop Board DQ57TMIntel®

Desktop Board DQ57TMLIntel®

Desktop Board DQ963FXIntel®

Desktop Board DQ963GSIntel®

Desktop Board DQ965COIntel®

Desktop Board DQ965GFIntel®

Desktop Board DQ965WCIntel®

Desktop Board DX38BTIntel®

Desktop Board DX48BT2Intel®

Desktop Board DX58OGIntel®

Desktop Board DX58SOIntel®

Desktop Board DX58SO2